# Can I make a Wi-Fi VoIP call on Google Voice without third party applications?

Tags: wi-fi, google-voice, voip

I can't seem to make pure Wi-Fi VoIP calls on Google Voice without a third party application such as GrooVe IP. Is this the case?

Comment: We are not in a position to answer why a certain app was coded by Google in one way or another.  You'll have to request this feature from Google directly.

Comment: @Chahk - So first question?

Comment: There used to be a way, but Google disabled it after too many people found out about it :(  Details in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately currently there is no way to make a pure VoIP outbound call via Google Voice on Android.

Previously, you could initiate a free call from Gmail on your PC, then press the `*` key on the keypad which would transfer the call to all other numbers connected to your GV account, and then you'd pick up the "call" on your cell phone and continue the conversation on your mobile which was still VoIP.  Once Google wised up to this feature being used too widely, they changed this functionality to [only allow this transfer for incoming calls only](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/115080?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks for the summary. I can only guess that the service was using too much bandwidth to offer for free?

Comment: Either that, out Google didn't want to get the carriers mad... Not yet anyway :)